# Erro ao usar uma variável incremental com ClosedXML e C#

Tags: c#, xml

Estou utilizando um while para ler dados de uma planilha e armazenar em uma lista. Ao executa o código recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Double'.
```

Apontando para a linha do IndicadorA2.

Obs.: estou utilizando ClosedXML; me certifiquei que nas linhas da planilha não tinham itens que sejam strings; ao usar o código fora do while o mesmo funciona perfeitamente.

```
while (true)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlanilhaTwo.Cell("A" + linha2.ToString()).ToString())) break;

                //Lendo as células
                double IndicadorA1 = (double)Planilha.Cell("C" + linha.ToString()).Value;
                double IndicadorB1 = (double)Planilha.Cell("D" + linha.ToString()).Value;

                double IndicadorA2 = (double)PlanilhaTwo.Cell("C" + linha2.ToString()).Value;
                double IndicadorB2 = (double)PlanilhaTwo.Cell("D" + linha2.ToString()).Value;

                double Erro = 6371 * Math.Acos(Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * (90 - IndicadorA1)) * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * (90 - IndicadorA2)) + Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * (90 - IndicadorA1)) * Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * (90 - IndicadorA2)) * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * (IndicadorB1 - IndicadorB2)));

                PlanA.Add(new PlanilhaTemp1((double)Planilha.Cell("A" + linha.ToString()).Value, (double)Planilha.Cell("B" + linha.ToString()).Value, (double)PlanilhaTwo.Cell("A" + linha2.ToString()).Value, "vinculado", Erro));

                linha2++;
            }
```

Comment: a mensagem é bem clara, você chegou a ver qual valor está sendo passado no momento que ocorre o erro?

Comment: o valor é o número -> -21,154896

Comment: eu acredito que seja pela vírgula, você aplicando o cast dessa forma o c# espera um valor double correto. O que você pode tentar, é trocar o (double) por um Convert.ToDouble

Comment: não funcionou, acredito que esteja relacionado a variável linha2, quando eu rodo o mesmo código sem incrementar essa variável o sistema funciona perfeitamente

Answer (score 0):

Consegui contornar a situação alterando a condição para sair do loop while

`while (linha2 <= ContaLinha2)
{
//if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlanilhaTwo.Cell("A" + linha2.ToString()).ToString())) break;`

```
                    //Lendo as células
                    double IndicadorA1 = (double)Planilha.Cell("C" + linha.ToString()).Value;
                    double IndicadorB1 = (double)Planilha.Cell("D" + linha.ToString()).Value;

                    double IndicadorA2 = (double)PlanilhaTwo.Cell("C" + linha2.ToString()).Value;
                    double IndicadorB2 = (double)PlanilhaTwo.Cell("D" + linha2.ToString()).Value;

                    double Erro = 6371 * Math.Acos(Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * (90 - IndicadorA1)) * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * (90 - IndicadorA2)) + Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * (90 - IndicadorA1)) * Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * (90 - IndicadorA2)) * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * (IndicadorB1 - IndicadorB2)));

                    PlanA.Add(new PlanilhaTemp1((double)Planilha.Cell("A" + linha.ToString()).Value, (double)Planilha.Cell("B" + linha.ToString()).Value, (double)PlanilhaTwo.Cell("A" + linha2.ToString()).Value, "vinculado", Erro));

                    linha2++;
                }
```